# First-Line-Indent setting of Core Text not working in iPhone5s/6

Tags: ios, core-text

[update]Finally, I found the issue is between 4s/5 and 5s/6.
There are no any first line indent in 5s/6 simulator,and real phone.
iOS version is 8.2.

<strike>Indent setting works well in a 8.1.2(5c) iPhone and simulator, but in my ip6 and another 5s(both 8.1.3) there are not any first line indent.</strike>

see screenshot:

[image]

Any one meet same issue?

```
// indent
    CTParagraphStyleSetting indentSetting;
    indentSetting.spec = kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierFirstLineHeadIndent;
    indentSetting.value = &indent;
    indentSetting.valueSize = sizeof(float);

    CTParagraphStyleSetting settings[] = {lineBreakMode,paragraphSpacing,LineSpacing,alignmentSetting,indentSetting};
    CTParagraphStyleRef paragraphStyle = CTParagraphStyleCreate(settings, 5);   //第二个参数为settings的长度

    textStyle = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
            (id)fontColor.CGColor, kCTForegroundColorAttributeName,
            fontRef, kCTFontAttributeName,
            kernRef,kCTKernAttributeName,
            paragraphStyle,kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName,
            nil]

    attString=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:textStyle]; //1

    CTFramesetterRef framesetter =
    CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef)attString); //3

    CTFrameRef frame =
    CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter,
                             CFRangeMake(0, [attString length]), path, NULL);
    
    CTFrameDraw(frame, context); //4
```

Comment: What is the output in iOS 8.1.3 ? *not work at all* is not a valid problem description.